# GET http://localhost:4000/socket/adpage/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdEOS7G net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm making an auctions web application and integrating SocketIo for my Auctions and more functionalities since this is the case, I have used firebase for my storage and whenever i host this app on localhost the error pop ups and indicates that the socketio is not being used and help properly I'm sharing my server.js and socket.js file
to understand it more clearly

```js
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();
const connectDb = require("./db/dbconnect");
const { createServer } = require("http");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
const swaggerDoc = require("./documentation/swaggerSetup");
const socketio = require("./socket");
const multer = require("multer");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = socketio.init(server);
const adIo = socketio.initAdIo(server, "/socket/adpage");
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });
const firebaseApp = require("./utils/firebase");

app.use(express.json());
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true, //access-control-allow-credentials:true
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  next();
});
// Middleware

// Routes
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc));

// Default route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Server running");
});

app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/user", require("./routes/user"));
app.use("/ad", require("./routes/ad"));
app.use("/bid", require("./routes/bid"));
app.use("/room", require("./routes/room"));
app.use("/auction", require("./routes/auction"));
app.use("/upload", require("./routes/uploads"));

// Socket.io logic (move to a separate module if it gets more complex)
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Socket IO client connected");

  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    console.log("Socket IO client disconnected");
  });

  socket.on("leaveHome", () => {
    socket.disconnect();
  });
});

adIo.on("connect", (socket) => {
  // socket.join('testroom')
  socket.on("joinAd", ({ ad }) => {
    socket.join(ad.toString());
    console.log(`User joined room ${ad}`);
  });
  socket.on("leaveAd", ({ ad }) => {
    socket.leave(ad.toString());
    console.log(`Left room ${ad}`);
  });
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User has disconnect from ad");
  });
});

// Error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
});

// Connect to MongoDB and Initialize server
connectDb()
  .then(() => {
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    server.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Failed to connect to the database:", err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

```js
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
let io;
let adIo;

exports.init = (server) => {
  io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: process.env.CLIENT_BASE_URL,
      methods: ["*"],
      allowedHeaders: ["*"],
    },
  });
  return io;
};

exports.initAdIo = (server, path = "/socket/adpage") => {
  adIo = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: process.env.CLIENT_BASE_URL,
      methods: ["*"],
      allowedHeaders: ["*"],
    },
    path: path,
  });
  return adIo;
};

exports.getIo = () => {
  if (!io) {
    throw new Error("Socket.io not initialized");
  }
  return io;
};

exports.getAdIo = () => {
  if (!adIo) {
    throw new Error("Socket.io not initialized");
  }
  return adIo;
};
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? What  is process.env.CLIENT_BASE_URL?